# Javascript filled unsorted list auto scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling to make this idea of mine work..

The idea is to auto-scroll the dynamically filled unsorted list.
This is how I've build the Unsorted List with List Items in JavaScript

```
  $.getJSON(sportlink_url + 'programma?gebruiklokaleteamgegevens=NEE&aantaldagen=' + programma_dagen + '&eigenwedstrijden=JA&thuis=JA&uit=JA&' + sportlink_clientID, function (uitslag) {
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(uitslag).length; i++) {
    //for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      var aanvangstijd = uitslag[i].aanvangstijd;
      var thuisteam = uitslag[i].thuisteam;
      var uitteam = uitslag[i].uitteam;
      var accommodatie = uitslag[i].accommodatie;
      var competitiesoort = uitslag[i].competitiesoort;
      var datumNumber = uitslag[i].datum.substring(0,2);
      var datumMonth = uitslag[i].datum.slice(-4);
      var datumMonthClean = datumMonth.substring(0,3);

      //Fetch the DIV
      var el = document.getElementById("match_program");

      //Create new list item
      var node = document.createElement("li");
      node.setAttribute('role', 'presentation');

      //Create ticketDiv
      var ticketDiv = document.createElement("div");
      ticketDiv.setAttribute('class', 'tg-ticket');

      //Create timeBox
      var timeBox = document.createElement("time");
      timeBox.setAttribute('class', 'tg-matchdate');
      timeBox.innerHTML = (datumNumber + " <span>" + datumMonthClean + "</span>");

      //Create matchdetail
      var matchDetail = document.createElement("div");
      matchDetail.setAttribute('class', 'tg-matchdetail');
      matchDetail.innerHTML = ("<h4>" + thuisteam + "<span>&emsp;-&emsp;</span>" + uitteam + " &emsp; | &emsp; " + aanvangstijd + ", " + accommodatie);

      //Create themeTag
      var themeTag = document.createElement("span");
      themeTag.setAttribute('class', 'tg-theme-tag');
      themeTag.innerHTML = (competitiesoort);

      //Build the hole thing
      ticketDiv.appendChild(timeBox);
      matchDetail.appendChild(themeTag);
      ticketDiv.appendChild(matchDetail)
      node.appendChild(ticketDiv);
      el.appendChild(node);
```

This is the Unsorted List in HTML

```
<ul id="match_program" class="tg-tickets tg-tabnav" role="tablist" data-autoscroll="">
</ul>
```

This is the function i'm currently using for auto-scroll, but it has .ulContent').height() > $('.ulContainer').height() and because my ulContent doesn't have a prefix height in CSS it's not going to work..

And I can't put a height prefix in CSS for the ulContent cause I don't know on forehand if it's going to be 500px of 800px, the unsorted list is being filled from a JSON string.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if($('.ulContent').height() > $('.ulContainer').height()) {
              setInterval(function () {
                start();
              }, 3000);
            }
        });
    
        function animateContent(direction) {
          var animationOffset = $('.ulContainer').height() - $('.ulContent').height();
          if(direction == 'up') {
            animationOffset = 0;
          }
        }
```

The animatie function is being called at the bottom of the HTML file just before the closing tags of the body

Comment: Can you maybe explain what "But of course that isn't working cause the list is only being filled while loading the page, there isn't a set height at that time..." means a bit more? And also shorten the code a little, removing code that is not really necessary?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen I've removed some of the code and added some more context

Comment: What is ticketDiv, matchDetail, node, el, .ulContent, .ulContainer? Where is animateContent called?

Comment: Please provide enough code constituting a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @LearningMathematics I re-added the ticketDiv etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to figure it out;

```
  var amountGames = Object.keys(uitslag).length
  var calulContent = amountGames * 116 + 500;
  var setulContent = calulContent + "px";
  document.getElementById('ulContent').style.height= setulContent;
```

That way the ulContent is always filled and the container uses a fixed number of 500px;